# Lubuntu 16.04 LTS Workspaces Missing

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, google-earth

1. Using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Was working perfectly.
2. Then I installed the following dependencies:

lsb-base
lsb-core
lsb-invalid-mta

3. Then installed the latest version of Google Earth for the OS from .deb
4. Decided to un-install GE which I did using Synaptic.
5. When I rebooted, my workspaces that had previously been in the taskbar were missing.
6. Went into Openbox Config (obconf) Workspace option is still there along with the three workspaces that were there before GE was un-installed.
7. How do I get the workspaces back into the taskbar where they originally were?

TIA.

UPDATE: Curiously enough, it is simply the visual representation of the workspace that is missing from the taskbar, i.e. the launcher shortcut.  If I use keyboard shortcut Superuser + f1/f2/f3, it switches to the appropriate workspace.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
OK so I solved the problem: The resolution is to go into the panel prefs, then add "desktop pager."  Select the position where you want it and voila! she is solved.